# How to customize iOS app UITabBar to look like iphone 11's bottom bar on iOS 13

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, swift5, uitabbar

How should I customize ios app UITabBar to look like iphone 11's bottom bar which is shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: You should implement a custom tabbar using `UIVisualEffectView`

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out